# HTML Snapshot

Tags: asp.net, html, youtube, snapshot

Using asp.net, I need to generate a snapshot of an youtube video.
I have access to the code that youtube generates for integrating their vids into other sites.

Basically what I want to do is what HTML Snapshot does, take a picture of some html, but I`m only interested in the video.

How can I approach this in asp.net, (buying HTML Snapshot is not an option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/Screenshot-of-Webpage-with-ASP-NET-AID398.aspx

It even has the code you need and everything.  You'll obviously have to modify it to fit your needs, but that site provides the basic code you need for getting a screenshot of a website problematically.

If you just want a snapshot of the video, then you'll have to crop it.  Since the video picture will always be in the same place, you can simply crop out the  extra stuff that you don't need. http://michael.sivers.co.uk/post/2007/08/Crop-and-resize-an-image-in-ASPNET.aspx

Comment: hey, thanks a bunch, your post lead me to

http://blog.taiki.be/index.php/2008/07/generating-screenshots-of-webpages-using-net/

which was exactly what i was looking for